# Do I need to reload Tailwind CSS every time I open an existing Astro project?

Tags: tailwind-css, astrojs, tailwind-ui, tailwind-3, tailwind-elements

Yesterday I created a new Astro project and installed Tailwind CSS. Today, I opened it, and it seems like Tailwind CSS is working strangely.

Do I need to reload Tailwind CSS every time I open an existing project, or is it enough to run `npm run dev` to run Astro?